# Git undo merge attempt

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I have working directory (#1) which has vendor directory(#2) in it. There is one dependency which I wanted to pull manually without composer (php version of npm/gem). I was working in #1, haven't saved/commited changes, when I decided I want to update library in #2. I navigated to vendor/myname, and did git pull repository.

Unfortunately it started to pull and merge to #1, instead of creating new directory in vendor folder.

Now I have:

- #1 folder with my changes
- #1 folder with files I don't want from wrong repository
- #1 merge conflicts such as composer.json, Readme.md... (general files)

I want to "undo" this last git pull without loosing any changes I did to folder #1. How can I do this?

Comment: Git prevents pull or merge if there are uncommitted changes, are you sure this is what hapepned?

Comment: @CharlesB It aborted merge, projects are not jet merged. I know nothing about git preventing before pull...

Answer (score 196, accepted):

`git merge --abort` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: In older git versions:

  git reset --merge

Comment: It works, but unhelpfully tells you nothing. Do a `git status` to confirm.-

Answer (score 22):

Modern Git:

```
git merge --abort
```

Older:

```
git reset --merge
```

Old-school (warning: will discard all your local changes):

```
git reset --hard
```

But actually, it is worth noticing that `git merge --abort` is only equivalent to `git reset --merge` given that `MERGE_HEAD` is present. This can be read in the git help for merge command.

```
git merge --abort is equivalent to git reset --merge when MERGE_HEAD is present.
```

After a failed merge, when there is no `MERGE_HEAD`, the failed merge can be undone with `git reset --merge` but not necessarily with `git merge --abort`, **so they are not only old and new syntax for the same thing**. Personally I find `git reset --merge` much more useful in everyday work.

Answer (score 4):

With Git 2.10 (Q3 2016), you will know what to do, because `git status` will propose the `git merge --abort` option.

See [commit b0a61ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0a61ab23c0fd51a1b641b481e6a63f8661a8f9f) (21 Jul 2016) by [Matthieu Moy (`moy`)](https://github.com/moy).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5a2f4d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a2f4d3eef5c69ceb94bf25b7a1fb38a2af24921), 03 Aug 2016)</sup>

> ### `status`: suggest '`git merge --abort`' when appropriate
>
> We already suggest '`git rebase --abort`' during a conflicted rebase.
> Similarly, suggest '`git merge --abort`' during conflict resolution on '`git merge`'.